# How can I save thumbnails in this script?

Tags: php

This is the script I am using to resize images in my site. But I don't know how to add a feature to save thumbnails of that images.
If I can save the thumb, it will be possible to use that thumb later without using this script again and again.

```
<?php
    $time=time();
    $neww = 65;
    $newh = 87;
    $file=htmlspecialchars($_GET['file']);
    list(, , $type,)=getimagesize($file);

    if($type==1) {
        $funci='imagecreatefromgif';
    } //$funco='imagegif';}

    if($type==2) {
        $funci='imagecreatefromjpeg';
    } //$funco='imagejpeg';}

    if($type==3) { 
        $funci='imagecreatefrompng';
    } //$funco='imagepng';}

    if($type) {
        $im1 = $funci($file);
        $im2=imagecreatetruecolor($neww,$newh);
        imagecopyresized($im2, $im1, 0,0,0,0,$neww,$newh, imagesx($im1), imagesy($im1));

        header('Content-type: image/gif');
        imagegif($im2);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Vinod, I see no reason for deleting an entire code, do you? Rollbacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`imagegif`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) already does that for you if you pass the location of a file to which you want to save to as 2nd parameter to that function.

```
imagegif($im2);    //output raw image stream directly
imagegif($im2, 'path/to/image_save.gif');    //saves to the file at mentioned path
```

Although, it must be noted that if `path/to/image_save.gif` already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: it worked!! Thanks... The image generated by this scrip seems to lack quality. can you suggest a line of code or a modification to the same to get 100% quality? All Iant is to reduce the image resolution...

Comment: That's a problem with GIF format. GIF has 256 colors and JPEG has 4,294,967,296 colors. So, try using [`imagejpeg`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) or even better [`imagepng`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) for virtually lossless compression. By the way, since this new question is out of scope for this post, I recommend you to ask a new question and also read about [`PHP GD`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

Comment: Can you also upvote the answer because it helped? :)

Comment: just did it!
I have added a new post, about image quality. can u help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053868/low-quality-thumb-from-image-resize-script

Comment: @VinodKumar I will recommend you to use ImageMagick. http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php